# How does a library author provide feedback to an arbitrary calling application or library

Tags: python, callback, progress-bar

I'm writing some code that I would like to package as a library. It could be called from a UI, or another library, and it is not known in advance. What sort of mechanism is required to provide status or feedback to the caller?

My first thought was a callback:

```py
def callback(status):
    print(status)

def do_stuff(some_objects, callback = None)
    for something in some_objects:
        status = stuff()
        if callback:
            callback(status)
```

But in my very limited experience, my understanding is that would generally require knowledge of the callback structure. Is that onus on the lower library to define the structure of the callback function?

I'm used to just passing UI references and such to lower level functions, which obviously tightly couples that code and isn't suitable for a library.

Note: my previous question talked more about nested functions and callbacks. I'm trying to understand what options there are for defining behaviors of lower level functions, so they can pass information back to higher level functions. I'm somewhat near ground zero, so I have a lot of decisions to make as I see it potentially lasting a long time.

Comment: It's hard to say, you've given no real context. What's the alternative you're considering? Have you tried it out?

Comment: I don't know what the alternative is. Most of my other programming has just been tightly coupled... I would pass a UI control reference down to the `do_stuff` function, so it would update it directly.

Comment: It's just a variable so you'll have to treat it like any other variable. It can be passed explicitly, put as a member in a class, be global or hardcoded in local scope. But as said above, it's hard to say anything without knowing the context.

Comment: I'm using python, so would this be a good use of `**kwargs` to pass the callback function as a keyword to A(), and make sure I pass **kwargs to the nested functions until I finally check for the existence of a callback in do_stuff() and call if necessary? Are there specific mechanisms for passing a callback through a calling chain like I described?

Comment: @Brian Passing `**kwargs` is just passing arbitrary keywords arguments. In your case, you have a very specific argument, so I would suggest against using `**kwargs`. There is no special mechanism for doing what you want, it all boils down to how you're designing your code. The options are in my comment above, and the best choice depends solely on how all the UI code is connected and how you want the user to interface with it.

Comment: It also depends on what the code does. Do you really need a configurable callback, for instance? Do the function that use the callback really need to be so nested, or can it be called directly instead? Is using a callback even the correct solution, or is there another way you can design the code? So everything depends on how you want the code to be designed, and whatever choice you make comes with advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: That's fair. I want to be able to present the status in various forms. I'd like `do_stuff()` to inform the caller what iteration it is on, and there could be many callers in various forms. Is there a name or pattern associated with the different techniques you described? I read a few Python questions mentioning `yield` but that was beyond my knowledge, so I had no idea if it was a good fit. I suppose I'm looking for some options, but maybe my scope is too broad.

Comment: The scope is a bit too broad. What you want to do is logging, and there are many different ways to go about. I don't know the code's limitations, but a simple solution would be to have a global callback that any function can call. That easy but makes it harder to do threading (but that might not be an issue?). You could also put the functions in a class and have the callback as a member to the class, which makes it easier for a different sets of functions to have different callbacks, instead of having to constantly setting the global callback between funciton calls.

Comment: You could do some Google searches for _"programming logging techniques",_ along with _"best practices",_ or something like that to find more information that suits your needs.

Comment: Okay, that's a good idea. I suspect what I learn from that would be applicable to other scenarios.

Comment: The usual mechanism of controlling the length of parameter lists is to group them into structures.  In particular, if these various layers are (or can reasonably be made to be) members of a class, the callback can be stored as an instance attribute and thus be available in all of them.  Objects of such classes are often created as needed and quickly discarded.  If this sounds relevant to your use case I can of course write it as an answer.

Comment: I think I have a more concrete and direct question...I'll edit

Comment: As Ted Klein Bergman suggested, for me this smells to using the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) Python  module

Comment: Thanks @progmatico, I actually just started with the logging module, and it is surprisingly flexible and convenient. I'm also looking to do things like update a progress bar and the like, but I think I figured that out too. Thanks for the tips!